# SQL If parameter is null search all

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, null

I have a JSF page where users can search by five options, and can choose how many of those options they search by (0-5). The database has no NULL values.

Currently I have a horrendous piece of code that builds that SQL statement, but I would like to just have one parameterized statement.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
   WHERE col1 = 'dave' 
     AND col2 = 'Smith' 
     AND col3 = '3/2/2014' 
     AND col4 = '12345' 
     AND col5 = '67890' 
ORDER BY col5 DESC
```

Is there a way to detect an empty/null value in the search criteria e.g  col5=''
And just return all results for that column?

So that if the search criteria was just `col1='dave'` then the statment would act as if the input was

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
   WHERE col1 = 'dave' 
ORDER BY col5 DESC
```

Comment: What is your DB system?

Comment: Database is Oracle 11g

Comment: have you tried `OR` operator instead `AND`?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this in SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE (col1 = @col1 or @col1 is null) and
      (col2 = @col2 or @col2 is null) and
      . . .
ORDER BY col5 DESC;
```

But, you may not want to.  If you are using indexes to speed your searches, then the use of `or` can impede the use of the indexes in many databases (but apparently not in Oracle).  This is also true of `coalesce()`, which could be used as:

```
WHERE col1 = coalesce(@col1, col1) and
      col2 = coalesce(@col2, col2) and
      . . .
```

If you are constructing the query anyway, then do it in the statement.  The logic is like:

```
if @col1 is not null then
    @where = concat(@where, " and col1 = '", @col1, "'")
end if;
if @col2 is not null then
    @where = concat(@where, " and col2 = '", @col2, "'")
end if;
```

This will construct the correct `where` clause that can use available indexes.

There is one downside to this approach.  You cannot pre-compile the statement for all parameter values.  The statement would need to be recreated every time new values are input (this would normally be an acceptable amount of overhead because you are dealing with user input).

Comment: Oracle is able to optimize   "OR :param IS NULL" because it evaluates to constant (it same as "NULL IS NULL" )

Comment: @jbaliuka . . . Thank you for the information.  Many databases don't recognize that condition when deciding to use indexes.

Comment: They call it "Adaptive Cursor" feature http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-sqlplanmanagement-101938.html

Comment: @jbaliuka . . . Is Oracle smart enough to use indexes for `col1 = coalesce(:col1, col1)`?

Comment: No, it won't do it automatically. You have to add function based index or to index a virtual column. Actually I am using JDBC driver level SQL parser derived from jsqlparser library to transform reporting queries, I add VPD feature for other databases this way too https://github.com/jbaliuka/sql-analytic

Comment: @jbaliuka from Oracle perspective this construct is essence of pure evil. One of the most common used anti-patterns.  If I simplify it, you want to use full table scan if parameter is null but you want to use index if it is not null. If the statement if not "bind-aware" then Oracle might start randomly flipping between plans.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `trim` to change empty value `''` to `null` and then use `coalesce` to replace `null` with value from `col5` as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE col1 = 'dave' 
AND col2 = 'Smith' 
AND col3 = '3/2/2014' 
AND col4 = '12345' 
AND col5 = coalesce(trim('67890'),col5)
ORDER BY col5 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE (col1 = :col1 OR :col1 IS NULL)
    AND (col2 = :col2 OR :col2 IS NULL)
    AND (col3 = :col3 OR :col3 IS NULL)
    AND (col4 = :col4 OR :col4 IS NULL)
    AND (col5 = :col5 OR :col5 IS NULL)
    ORDER BY col5 DESC
```

It is more convenient to use named parameter instead of "?" in JAVA